# Equal weights constraints

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I have the following nonlinear contrained optimization problem, that im am solving in R using `solnp`:

```
max  F(w)
 w
   s.t.
 w_i >= 0 for all i
 sum(w) = 1
```

However, I would like to add an extra constraint but i'm not sure it is even possible. I would like all the `w`'s bigger than 0 to have equal weights. Something like:

```
max  F(w)
 w
   s.t.
 w_i >= 0 for all i
 sum(w) = 1
 w_i=w_j for all i,j where w_i,w_j>0
```

Does anyone if it is possible, and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a necessarily hard optimization problem given that your search space is completely determined. Essentially, given finite number of dimensions for `w_i`, you have a finite number of points in the `R^w` space that you want to search over. These are:

```
c(1, 0, 0, ..., 0)
c(0, 1, 0, ..., 0)
...
c(0, 0, ..., 1)
c(1/2, 1/2, 0, ..., 0)
c(1/2, 0, 1/2, ..., 0)
...
c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0, ..., 0)
...
c(1/n, 1/n, ..., 1/n)
```

so on. You get the idea.
Which means that you can just evaluate your function over these points and pick the combination which maximizes `F`.

Does that sound about right or have I missed something critical?

Comment: Thanks, you are completely right! I thought the number of points would be infinite, but they are of course pinned down by the constraints.

Comment: However, the total size of the search space grows quite fast in `n`. It equals \sum_{a=1}^n \frac{n!}{a!(n-a)!}. And with `n=36` (as I was considering) this equals 68,719,476,735 possibilities :(

Comment: @Mace: You are right that the complexity of this is quite large. I am not sure if your constraint criterion fits into a proper optimization paradigm though.

Comment: No, me neither. However, I got your solution to work even with n=22, and that is fine for me... Thanks again